# Geting json from nodejs server but not able to display on ionic page- Cannot find a differ supporting, object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, ionic3

> GET Response: Welcome! home.ts:44:8
>
> POST Response:  Object { passed:true, message: "sdf" } home.ts:38:10
>
> ERROR  Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
> of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
> Arrays.

home.module.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Pipe } from 'angular2/core';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
export class HomePage {

  name: string;
  results: any;
 public results: result[];
constructor(private http: Http) {

}

checkName() {

  let data = {
          name: this.name
      };

      this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/checkname', data).pipe(
          map(res => res.json())
      ).subscribe(response => {
        this.results=response;
          console.log('POST Response:', response);
      });

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/checkname/' + this.name).pipe(
        map(res => res.json())
    ).subscribe(response => {
        console.log('GET Response:', response);
    });

}
}
```

home.ts

```
< ion-item *ngFor="let r of results"/>
{{ r.message }}
< /ion-item>
```

you can see from my output i am getting json from server nodejs but not able to display on ionic page.

Comment: Have you checked other answers with the similar error message?

Comment: yes. But i don't understand what to do whats wrong in it. Tried all solution.  So finally i asked my own qus. I jsut want to know where i am doing mistake.

Comment: All you need to do is to check what `results` is. ngFor will only work with Iterables

Comment: please be in detail as i am noob in ionic

Comment: how can i check. I am getting output on console like this Object { passed:true, message: "sdf" }

Comment: please post a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please ask to api team  send this type of response. if  array response you must be get in array format otherwise give error

```
[{ passed:true, message: "sdf" }]
```

Comment: thats a wow answer. You are right i am having wrong array format! Great work

Comment: glad to help keep it